# Laravel uploaded files are not going in the good folder

Tags: laravel, image, upload, storage

here my code :

```
Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs('/img/uploads/specialties', new File($validatedData['image_file']);
```

My system config file :

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

In local mode, when i upload an image, they are going into

> /public/storage/img/uploads/specialties

but in production they are going to

> /storage/app/public/img/uploads/specialties

What i tried : $ php artisan storage:link without success.

Anyone know how to change where uploaded files going in production ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution :

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('storage'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```